# EVERY TIME I RUN "npm run build" i got this error

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment

### this is the error shown in terminal when i run "npm run build"

```
'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reminder@0.1.0 build: `CI= react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the reminder@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

**this is my package.json**

### and i think i have error due to "build" : "CI= react-scripts build"

so please review my code and answer it

```
{
  "name": "reminder",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI= react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: did you use `npx create-react-app ...` ?

Comment: Why do you have that `CI=` ?